# Determining masses from radial velocity curves of eclipsing binaries

Tags: observational-astronomy, radial-velocity, eclipsing-star-systems

Is the statement

> From radial velocities or astrometry for eclipsing binaries, one obtains masses.

wrong, because only minimal masses can be obtained?

Comment: What is the source of the statement, please.

Comment: "one obtains masses" is a very vague statement. It can also refer to minimal masses I guess.

Comment: Thus, 

    'From RVs or astrometry for eclipsing binaries, one obtains minimal masses.' is correct?

Comment: Radial velocities

Comment: I find it difficult to judge the absolute truth of such short and out of context statements that you are asking also in other questions. I really think it could help if you provided more context. In this case the statement may be correct because if the binaries are eclipsing then the $\sin i$ degeneracy is broken and one can obtain the true masses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is correct. The inclination of an *eclipsing* binary can be estimated from the light curve (and is likely to be close to 90 degrees in order to produce an eclipse).

The radial velocity curves can then give $M_{1,2}\sin(i)$ and hence the component masses.